# Separate compilation for generics in Rust

Tags: c++, generics, rust

C++ has been criticized because it lacks separate compilation of templates. C++ templates are compiled for (virtually) each instantiation. What is the state of the things for Rust concerning separate compilation of generics ? My understanding is that it behaves like C++ except that instantiations are cached during the compilation of each crate. Is that correct ?

Comment: I’m a little hazy on where templates fit in in C++, but in Rust where macros are concerned you can get the expanded form with `--pretty expanded`. But not generics.

Comment: Actually, the real issue in C++ is not that templates are compiled for each instantiation: clever compilers perform memoization and have a cache of a number of "pre-compiled" instantiations of a template for a few given set of types/values. The main issue is *separate compilation* combined with `#include`, the template has to be in headers so is needlessly parsed in every single translation unit whether it uses it or not. This issue will disappear with modules (C++17 maybe ?).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know, generics are stored in some serialized form in the crate where they are defined. When used in another crate (library or binary) they are instantiated from this serialized form. So they are monomorphized the same way as are C++ templates but the overhead of repeated parsing of unnecessary code is avoided.

Answer (score 2):

From the tutorial docs:

> The Rust compiler compiles generic functions very efficiently by monomorphizing them. Monomorphization is a fancy name for a simple idea: generate a separate copy of each generic function at each call site, a copy that is specialized to the argument types and can thus be optimized specifically for them. In this respect, Rust's generics have similar performance characteristics to C++ templates.
>   http://doc.rust-lang.org/0.11.0/tutorial.html#generics

**EDIT:** this didn't really answer your question, did it?

Comment: That text is exactly why I conjectured that it's the same as in C++. I would like to hear something more explicit, though.

Comment: The "similar performance characteristics" here refers to runtime performance, meaning that compilation is performed separately for each copy and hence no runtime overhead. This sentence does not exactly refer to the compile time.

Answer (score 2):

Generic types and functions are monomorphized. However, it's possible to use traits without generics.

This is a generic function. It will be monomorphized.

```
fn get_length<T: Collection>(collection: &T) -> uint {
    collection.len()
}
```

This is an equivalent non-generic function. Only one copy of this function will be included in the binary.

```
fn get_length(collection: &Collection) -> uint {
    collection.len()
}
```

Note that we couldn't make a function that receives a `Collection` by value, because `Collection` is a trait, and thus it has no specific size. A generic function is required in this case.

There are some things you can't do with generics and some things you can't do with trait references. With trait references, you need a trait, obviously. With generics, you can't have a vector of collections where the collections are of different types (e.g. you couldn't put a `Vec<int>` and a `String` in that vector), but you can with trait references: a `Vec<&Collection>` can contain a `&Vec<int>` and a `&String`.